# Visualize Jasmine tests in TeamCity

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, teamcity-8.0

I'm using Chutzpah console to run all tests in teamcity.
Command line options:

```
/junit jasmine_report.html /teamcity /failOnError
```

This produces JUnit report in xml format. How can i visualize this as TeamCity tab (as Specflow, etc.).

It will be great to see all passed/not passed tests. I know there is Tests tab, but it is not human-readable one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Chutzpah, but have you looked at jasmine-reporters? It is a collection of reporters supporting Jasmine 1.x or 2.x, and it includes a TeamCity reporter. Maybe you could add this extra reporter to your spec runner to get better TeamCity reporting?

https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters

Answer (score 0):

To show some html as tab on build details page, follow [next instructions](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results).

Also jasmine-reporters @bloveridge mentioned allows on-the-fly reporting about tests and test would be shown on tests tab.